# Accepting Request with loading interface (Using CodeIgniter)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

How to alert the user that sends the request if the requested user will approved the request.

**Optional:**
When there is now alert to the user that send the request. The requested user will wait for the verificiation of the user that send the request.

**Example**
Requesting a battle on Tetris battle facebook.

Need help!!

a little idea will help!

Comment: If you are using some sort of API, than the answer would be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for your purposes I think it would be better to use `XHR` **long polling** requests (you can see [this link](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) for basic tutorial). For what you want to achieve the scheme would be next:

1. Each user `x` polls, say *database* or *memcache* (if you got
   plenty users to work with) storage;
2. When new request to a
   specific user `x` is made by user `y`, it gets inserted into your
   storage;
3. Next time that specific user `x` polls your storage, he
   would find that there is something new to him - a request from user
   `y`.

That is the basic idea, but really, the question of instant notifications is quite complex and indeed requires a lot of optimization techniques and correct implementation, so your polling requests will not hang server.

The other things you might try is **WebSockets** and **EventSource**, but they a bit more advanced then simple **long polling**.

Hope that gives you idea on how to achieve this, and by the way, this issue isn't really about CodeIgniter.

**Update**

Well, if you got some sort of on-line game, you should get a bit more hardcore on it : ) I was asking sort of a similar question not so long ago in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471034/performance-of-event-source), but it was really about event notification server implementation, which uses `sockets` and `event-source`; it *could* be suitable for your purposes, however, if you are planning to write really serious stuff, try to start working with **WebSockets** - it's more advanced, but will give you functionality for mature real-time web-systems (at least I assume it will).

Here's a good [tutorial](http://buildnewgames.com/websockets/) I've found when was interested in it, might help you as well.

And about redirect - it's no big deal to properly handle some output from database and act accordingly with `JavaScript` - redirect both users in your case.

Comment: thanks..but i need to use the MVC format..Is it possible to use MVC format?

Comment: @Zurreal: Sure thing. Just include `.js` files in view, and handle `ajax` requests with `controller-model`. There's no big difference.

Comment: i get the idea..but part of my project is like battle or PVP..
wherein the user x will send request to user y. and yeah..the request will be stored in the database. but what im trying to achieve now is if the user Y accept the request..both user x and user y will now be redirected to another page with there data profile. i know its really complicated,,sorry to ask about this..im really new and interested to learn. :)

Comment: @Zurreal: Updated my answer. Don't forget to mark question as "answered", if that's it : )

Comment: in redirect part..how can i get the other user to redirect to other page? :)

Comment: @Zurreal: if user `y` accepts the request, he writing in database some event - event that both `x` and `y` will read from database, and if it matches some conditions, they both will get redirected.

Comment: i get it now..but im trying to implement now..thanks alot!!
is it ok..if i comment here if i got some problem or errors? :) 
to ask you again?^_^

Comment: I suppose you could, but it would be better for `Stack Overflow` to make another question post if you have one.