# Server optimization for ajax-heavy Apache+Mysql+PHP site

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, apache, optimization

I've looked around and haven't found a pre-existing answer to this question.

### Info

My site relies on Ajax, Apache, Mysql, and PHP.

I have already built my site and it works well however as soon as too many users begin to connect (when receiving roughly 200+ requests per second) the server performs very poorly.

This site is very reliant on ajax. The main page of the site performs an ajax request every second so if 100 people are online, I'm receiving at least 100 requests per second.

These ajax queries invoke mysql queries on the server-side. These queries return small datasets. The returned datasets will change very often so I'd imagine caching would be ineffective.

---

### Questions

**1)** What configuration practices would be best to help me increase the maximum number of requests per second? This applies to Ajax, Mysql, PHP, and Apache.

**2)** For Apache, do I want persistent connections (the KeepAlive directive) to be "On" or "Off"? As I understand, Off is useful if you are expecting many users, but On is useful for ajax and I need both of these things.

**3)** When I test the server's performance on serving a plain, short html page with no ajax (and involving only 1 minor mysql query) it still performs very poorly when this page gets 200+ requests per second. I'd imagine this must be due to apache configuration / server resources. What options do I have to improve this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If your website is some kind of a web-service with heavy AJAX, I could advise you to change approach of requesting server. Once a second - is very simple way and not reliable; try long-polling or event-source instead. You could also look at some questions I've previously asked - there are some similar issue there and great answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471034/performance-of-event-source

Comment: Why do you have ajax calls every second? I think you may need to analyze your approach.

Comment: Ajax calls once per second to inform client-side of rapidly changing server-side data. Is that wrong?

Comment: As you can see it is - you server performance is clearly getting poor.

Comment: Yes if it is going to have even a decent amount of traffic you need to look into using sockets or long polling.

Comment: @pitchinnate Ok that's good to know, I'll certainly look into it. And grimv01k thanks for the link I'm checking it out. I'm also going to edit/extend my question in light of some new testing.

Comment: FYI 200 requests per second = 17,280,000 page views per day. While you may have small spurts of traffic this high I highly doubt you will have continuous traffic at this rate. As the link states it is mainly a memory issue the best way to improve is to add more memory.

Comment: Part of your problem may be fundamental to the technology stack itself. Sounds like you should probably be using Node.js instead of PHP, PostgreSQL instead of MySQL, and web sockets instead of AJAX.

Comment: You should really consider changing your approach. There is huge argument about rendering the html server side completely and doing each part via ajax.

* Are all the users getting the same response? if so add caching to the calls so the server avoids calculating the response.
* You should really read about how facebook renders pages and avoids huge ajax requests https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=389414033919
* Apache should be handling more than 17m pv a day. if not than your not closing connections or his working too hard with response. did you check if the db malperform?

Comment: I'm only passing json via ajax!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the actual user need the caching can be implemented in different patterns. In many cases the users don't really need updates per every second and/or they can be cached for longer period of times and just make it look like it updates a lot. It depends...

Just to give some ideas:

1. Do every user need to get really unique, user specific responses from ajax requests or is it same or similar to all or sub groups of the users?
2. Does it make sense to have every second updates for every user?
3. Can the users notice the difference if the data is cached for, let's say, 10 seconds?
4. If the data is really unique for every user, but doesn't get updated for every user per every second, couldn't you use data refreshing (invalidate cached data when the data actually changes)?

Answer (score 0):

I used requirejs to lazy load the js, html and css files. For server to serve loads of assets you need to keep the `KeepAliveTimeout` to 15